# Can't map property, Consider to declare/implement a mapping method

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

When I try to compile my application it shows me this error, the whole application was generated with Jhipster.

Detail Description Error: [ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Desktop/Devs/CURTIPIELES/curti-back/src/main/java/com/curtipieles/app/service/mapper/LeatherMapper.java:[21,16] Can't map property "com.curtipieles.app.domain.Usage leather.usage.usage" to "java.lang.String usageName". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.lang.String map(com.curtipieles.app.domain.Usage value)".

Error
[image]

This is my LeatherMapper:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {LeatherFamilyMapper.class, LeatherHasColorMapper.class, LeatherHasUsageMapper.class})
public interface LeatherMapper extends EntityMapper<LeatherDTO, Leather> {

    @Mapping(source = "family.id", target = "familyId")
    @Mapping(source = "family.name", target = "familyName")
    @Mapping(source = "color.id", target = "colorId")
    @Mapping(source = "color.id", target = "colorName")
    @Mapping(source = "usage.id", target = "usageId")
    @Mapping(source = "usage.usage", target = "usageName")
    LeatherDTO toDto(Leather leather);

    @Mapping(source = "familyId", target = "family")
    @Mapping(source = "colorId", target = "color")
    @Mapping(source = "usageId", target = "usage")
    Leather toEntity(LeatherDTO leatherDTO);

    default Leather fromId(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Leather leather = new Leather();
        leather.setId(id);
        return leather;
    }
}
```

This is my LeatherDTO (I do not put the Getters And Setters so as not to lengthen the question so much)

```java
public class LeatherDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long id;

    private String imageUrl;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private Boolean status;

    private Instant creationDate;

    private Boolean isNew;


    private Long familyId;

    private String familyName;

    private Long colorId;

    private String colorName;

    private Long usageId;

    private String usageName;
```

This is my Leather Class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "leather")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Leather implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
    "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Boolean status;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Instant creationDate;

    @Column(name = "is_new")
    private Boolean isNew;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "leathers", allowSetters = true)
    private LeatherFamily family;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "leathers", allowSetters = true)
    private LeatherHasColor color;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "leathers", allowSetters = true)
    private LeatherHasUsage usage;
```

This is my LeatherHasUsage Class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "leather_has_usage")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class LeatherHasUsage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
    "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Boolean status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "leatherHasUsages", allowSetters = true)
    private Usage usage;

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public LeatherHasUsage status(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
        return this;
    }
```

This is my LeatherHasColor class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "leather_has_color")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class LeatherHasColor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Boolean status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "leatherHasColors", allowSetters = true)
    private Color color;
```

This is my LeatherFamily class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "leather_family")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class LeatherFamily implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
    "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Boolean status;

    @Column(name = "is_new")
    private Boolean isNew;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Instant creationDate;
```

Comment: How do you want `usage.usage` *(type `Usage`)* to map to `usageName` *(type `String`)*?

Comment: That's the name of the "Usage" attribute, only I defined it that way.
     @Column (name = "usage")
     private String usage;

Comment: The error message says that `usage.usage` is of type `com.curtipieles.app.domain.Usage`, not of type `String`.

Comment: but in com.curtipieles.app.domain.Usage the "Usage" attribute is declared as a string, I don't really understand what happens.

Comment: I don't either, but that because I have no idea what `Leather` is, or what `LeatherDTO` is, or what the `family`, `color`, and `usage` properties of `Leather` is.

Comment: The name of Usage is declared as "Usage" that's why usage.usage or usageUsage is seen, what I don't understand is why I get this error from mapStruct if usage and colors have practically the same structure but colors don't get an error and I don't know really for whatever reason.

Comment: Of course I want help, in fact I apologize if I am not being clear enough, I am new to the development world ... And also new to using StackOverflow if you want to see something I can show you.

Comment: Then **edit** the question and show us the `Leather` class, and the classes of the fields it has (`Family`?, `Color`?, `Usage`?, ...), like I already indicated we'd need to see in order to help you.

Comment: The question is a bit long, if there are problems, I can also attach photos if you wish ... I greatly appreciate your time, thank you

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You correctly formatted the original code using `\`\`\`java`, so why couldn't you do that for all the rest of the code you added? Anyway, it's been fixed.

Comment: Why did you show class `Usage`? It's not used anywhere. The `usage` field of `Leather` is type `LeatherHasUsage`, not type `Usage`. Did you forget your own model? --- FYI: `color` has the same issue, but it doesn't fail since you only use `color.id`. I mean, you do use that twice in the mapping, and that's allowed, but curious/suspicious.

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected, and yes, that's what I was telling you ... They handle practically the same structure but color does not give problems and something curious is that I try to change usage.usage to usage.id, but the same compiler refers me to what if or if it is usage.usage

Comment: Oh, so now the error message was correct all along? `usage` is type `LeatherHasUsage`, and hence `usage.usage` is type `Usage`, just like the error message said. Imagine that! --- And `color` works because you don't attempt to use `color.color`, you instead map `color.id` to `colorName` for some unknown reason *(hint: reason is copy/paste error)*.

Comment: Isn't is obvious? `usage` is type `LeatherHasUsage`, so `usage.usage` is type `Usage`, which means that `usage.usage.usage` is the type `String` value you're looking for. (Well, we can't actually see that anymore, since you removed the `Usage` class again. *<sigh>*) --- Similar for `color`. --- **The real question is:** Should `usageId` really be mapped from `usage.id`? Or should it maybe be mapped from `usage.usage.id`? Which of those two `id` values is it supposed to use, huh?

Comment: You really have left me unanswered ...

I need to use usageId (the same for colors) since in my project, this is the attribute that I will inject into leather, this as a result should throw me a JSON that inside has two arrays that are (all the UsageId that I want to inject and all the ColorsId that I want to inject) So I don't really know if using usage.usage.id is the same, that's why I have no response

Comment: You already showed the `Leather` class, so why are you showing it again, and why are you doing it as an image when I already said "Please **do not upload images** of code/errors when asking a question"? *FYI:* If you really have memory retention issues as severe as you're showing, I don't think programming is for you. --- How have I left you unanswered? You change `"usage.usage"` to `"usage.usage.usage"`, and likely also change `"usage.id"` to `"usage.usage.id"`, since you seemingly forgot you have an extra level of object, and do similar change for `color`, and your code should be all fixed.

Comment: Perfect, it seems that the solution of an error gave birth to another error jejeje. In the same way, I will thank you for this and the other life for the time invested. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution to the problem

> You change "usage.usage" to "usage.usage.usage", and likely also change "usage.id" to "usage.usage.id", since you seemingly forgot you have an extra level of object, and do similar change for color, and your code should be all fixed. - [comment by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093675/cant-map-property-consider-to-declare-implement-a-mapping-method/67095745#comment118596466_67093675)